# PHP Jquery DropDownSelectList Multiple Variables with same name

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the Select->DropDownCheckList from http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/demo.html... with a PHP back end...

This checklist submits (on form post) each selection as an individual variable, so for example:

brand=Apple
brand=Microsoft
brand=Google

And when doing $_POST["brand"] in php I only get 1 of them, not all three... is there a way I can iterate through these items or some other way to access them?  Alternatively does anyone know how to change the jquery plugin above to send back in the form brand=Apple,Microsoft,Google...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name the form field `name='myformfield[]'` rather than `name='myformfield'` in your HTML. The `[]` tells PHP that the field is an array.